# Как правильно выбрать ключи проекции для OpenStreetMap для отображения карты на сайте с помощью библиотеки OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, карты, координаты, openstreetmap, openlayers

Хочу, чтобы карта автоматически показывала город "Краснодар" по заданным мною координатам. Перепробовал много чего, но всё равно выдаёт не ту местность, что можно сделать?

```js
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
    var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(45.133516, 38.998197).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
    var zoom = 13;

    map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(position, zoom);
}
```

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#map {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Отслеживание перемещений транспорта OnLine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
    <script src="OpenLayers-2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script defer="defer" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного ошибся, и только сейчас понял, что сначала идёт координата долготы, а вслед за ней координата широты

```js
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
    var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(39.004301, 45.130331).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
    var zoom = 13;

    map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(position, zoom);
}
```